# Installed Ubuntu 11.10 alongside Windows 7 - getting grub> menu on boot

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, grub2

So, I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 just now, on my girlfriend's laptop. I used a USB stick and followed all the default options, choosing a partition size of 32GB for Ubuntu 11.10.

After installation completed, the machine rebooted and now all I'm left with is a command prompt like this:

grub>

I was expecting a boot menu rather than this, and I've idea how to proceed. Hoping someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This means that grub, as an application, has managed to load successfully, but something has stopped it from moving on to ubuntu. chances are this is a problem with the configuration file; although i'm surprised this happened on a fresh install.

The grub> prompt should allow you to restore your system.

As it's difficult to diagnose exactly what is wrong from just knowing you're dropped into the prompt, I recommend you read-up on this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#A.27.27grub.3E.27.27_Prompt_Booting

Simply however, I suspect you'll need to do the following:

- Seek the linux partition: `ls`
- Pick the parition you think you installed Ubuntu on
- Check that the linux parition has all the files: `ls (hdX,Y)/`, `ls (hdX,Y)/boot` and `ls (hdX,Y)/boot/grub` should all return the names of some files
- If not, change to another parition or come back here with the output
- Start the loaded menu: `configfile (hdX,Y)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- If this doesn't work, come back to askubuntu, or, if you're up to it, you can read how to write a rudimentary configuration in the link I included.
- Once you've got to Ubuntu in the terminal you must `sudo update-grub` to save changes.

Personally, if this is a fresh install, I might take a pop at just reinstalling Ubuntu and taking note of the more advance options, specifically where to install grub to.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I reinstalled, and now get a grub rescue prompt. With ls, only ls (hd0,5)/ returns anything, including boot/. If I try ls (hd0,5)/boot/ (or any other dir) I get an error: out of disk message.

Comment: FWIW I was able to boot into Ubuntu using the Live CD, then run the grub-install and update-grub2 commands. They reported installing a config. When I rebooted, I was back to the grub rescue prompt, with the out of disk error.

Comment: ok- just out of interest do you have more than one hard-disk? if you do then you might need to point your bios to boot from the right one (a quick way of doing this would be to use your bios boot menu...)

Comment: No, just one disk.

Comment: Tried the graphical Boot Repair program, and still no luck.

Comment: This is beginning to get a little too beyond my knowledge of grub; I have three final suggestions though: 1 - Try installing using the alternative CD (I've seen comments about this being successfully used on HP Laptops at least [ http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download ]. 2 - Have a look around http://ubuntuforums.org/ (This site is good for quick questions, but I think you're more likely to find someone who's an expert in grub rescue on there,) and 3 - Have a look at installing using Wubi. - Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same exact issue until I changed the SATA controller mode in the BIOS setup from AHCI to Native IDE.