# Attempt to install Ubuntu 12.10 from Windows but get GRUB instead

Tags: 12.10, grub2, windows, wubi

I have a Ubuntu ISO that I have just downloaded from ubuntu.com and used the Windows Installer (Wubi) to install Ubuntu, but when it boots, instead of Ubuntu I get some GRUB ... something.

I have looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84811/installed-ubuntu-11-10-alongside-windows-7-getting-grub-menu-on-boot) and attempted to follow the answer's advice, but all I've gotten back from attempting to use `ls` on any of the partitions is "Unknown filesystem". The other commands do nothing or complain about not being given arguments (I have no idea what arguments to give them and GRUB doesn't explain). I have Windows 7 x64, attempted to install Ubuntu 12.10 x64, and the hard drive is NTFS.

What am I supposed to do to get Ubuntu from here? Please note that I currently have absolutely no removable storage whatsoever, so there will be no booting from DVD for me.

Comment: I've submitted a proposed edit to mention you're in fact using Wubi (it wasn't overly clear from the description and Wubi seems rarely used in practice)

Comment: I'd suggest booting from a live USB/DVD and running the bootinfoscript to help figure out what's going on. See http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/